# IIS AppDomain unloading in an Azure environemnt

Tags: iis, azure, appdomain

As far as I understand, in a Windows Azure web role - every .svc is loaded in it's own App Domain. Does IIS ever unload the AppDomain duirng its process lifetime so that invocation (typically via a HTTP call) of the svc will trigger Application_Start() (again)?

Answer (score 2):

You may be running into IIS Recycling.  http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/kb/Disabling_IIS_app_pool_recycling

There are programmatic way to disable this, if that is what you want to do.